# Soyuz TMA-19M return

Tags: iss, crewed-spaceflight, soyuz-spacecraft

The launch of the next crew to ISS with Soyuz MS 1 has been delayed.
Why the return date of the current crew  on Soyuz TMA 19M remains unchanged?
An extension of their mission for ca. 2 weeks would have been good for science.

Answer (score 2):

Mission was already [extended](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Human_Spaceflight/Principia/New_landing_date_for_ESA_astronaut_Tim_Peake) for almost two more weeks. If their presence is needed, maybe mission will be extended once more, we don't know yet for sure.